# where wrong in my flash source (action script 3 )?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

```
myMC.buttonMode=true;
myMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_onClick);
myMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_onMouseOut);
var visited=false;


function fl_onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("fa/index.html"),"_self");
    visited=true;
}
function fl_onMouseOut(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (visited) {
        myMC.gotoAndStop("visited");
    }
}
myMC2.buttonMode=true;
myMC2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2_onClick);
myMC2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, f2_onMouseOut);
var visited2=false;

function f2_onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("en/index.html"),"_self");
    visited2=true;
}
function f2_onMouseOut(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (visited2) {
        myMC.gotoAndStop("visited");
    }
}
```

---

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.

Comment: It is hard to say from just looking at this part. Place some breakpoint and debug your code step by step. I would guess myMC or myMC2 is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that when you click on th MC, the whole page is replaced by another (`_self`). Therefore you can't expect Flash to remember the value of a variable (visited or visited2) next time it is displayed. To do this you will have to use a cookie or a session variable serverside.

And then, are you sure myMC and myMC2 exist? Try to trace them before doing anything. Are they clips on your stage (Flash), are they class properties?...

Comment: i replaced whole page,myMC and myMC2 exist , ... but this Error exist yet !
[Exept: how can i trace in adobe flash CS 5.5!?]